# Translation of 'apropos of nothing'

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, expresiones, palabras-raras

What might be the translation of *apropos*, as commonly used in American English, that Spanish speakers would use in identical situations, the context being *germane (to)*, in a broad sense?

Continuing that thought in context, is there an expression in Spanish that means the same as "apropos of nothing"?

Comment: It is simply "a propósito de" algo.

Comment: @Gustavson, thank you, the question was too broad, I amended it.

Comment: Who says or where did you **actually see or hear** "apropos of nothing"?

Comment: @Lambie It appears now and then in popular fiction narrative. I imagine that it might seem pompous in conversation.

Comment: It just that you said as commonly used in AmE, when, in fact, it isn't. That is what I was getting at....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The translation of "apropos of nothing" will vary according to context, for example:

- She kept smiling apropos of nothing. ([Source](https://www.lexico.com/definition/apropos_of_nothing)) (Continuaba/continuó sonriendo **sin motivo**).
- Suddenly, apropos of nothing, he said, `You're such an optimist.' ([Source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles-tesauro/apropos-of-nothing)) (De repente, **de la nada**, dijo: Eres todo un optimista.)
- Apropos of nothing, what do you think about her? (**(No tiene) Nada que ver, pero** ¿qué piensas de ella?)

Answer (score 1):

The most used equivalent for "apropos" would be "Hablando de..." (Speaking of...).

Apropos of cars, I bought one! -> Hablando de coches, ¡me he comprado uno!

About "apropos of nothing", it would depend on context, as @Gustavson already told. My suggestions:

- Por nada en especial (for no special reason)
- Sólo por curiosidad (just for curiosity)
- Sin venir a cuento (literally, without coming in the tale): Me pegó una hostia sin venir a cuento <- She hit me in the face apropos of nothing.